# Read files from the ISO in CosmosOS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, cosmos

I'm using the "Add files to ISO" option in the settings of my Visual Studio 2022 project that uses the latest version of the Cosmos devkit.

I've tried the VFS using FAT32, but this uses the hard drive.

I can't find anything from actually reading from this iso though, any help would be great!